# Is this an efficient and secure way to dynamically generate a function in python?

Tags: python, code-generation, dynamically-generated

So what I'm doing is dynamically generating a function that returns the output of a mathematical equation `f(x,y) = z` like so:

```py
def compile(self) -> callable[[tuple(float)], float]:
        # user input is something like: xsin(y) + 1 = xcos(y)
        # input is tokenised and syntax is analysed
        # tokens converted to 'eval-able' python code
        # this gives: axes[0]*np.sin(axes[1])+1-axes[0]*np.cos(axes[1])
        # this is stored in evalString

        def func(axes: tuple(float)) -> float:
            v = type(self).variables  # user-defined variables
            f = type(self).functions  # user-defined functions
            return eval(evalString)

        return func
```

Is there a better way to generate a function like this? I have been told to avoid using `exec()` due to security issues, but have also been told that `eval()` isn't much better. I believe that *most* ways of executing potentially malicious code should be ruled out within the compilation stages, but I am aware that this may not be true and will require further testing.

I am also wondering if using `eval()` is the best/most efficient way to approach to this or if I should do/use something else?

Many thanks!

Comment: There probably is, but it's very difficult to tell what you are doing here for a few reasons: there are no clear I/O examples, the code depends on things you haven't included, and it appears you've created some kind of tokenizer without providing any information about it.

Comment: There's also the option of generating a Python AST tree, which might be easier or harder depends on your use case. ■ For the exec/eval, if you can ensure that all the possible code that you generate are "safe" (e.g. with a white list of callable functions), it should be safe (subject to your implementation bugs)